# Why is this happening? saveInstanceState=null

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Error]

The above issue arises once in two debug. And the weird thing is app doesn't crashes, it stops responding.

[image]

What does this mean? And what wrong is happening inside?

Comment: did you checked this solution? http://tinyurl.com/nnjwg3t

Comment: @zkminusck Thanks for your response.But I am not asking the solution. I want this issue to be explained. Why this is happening. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read [the documentation on this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), it will help you out a lot.

The `savedInstanceState` field is set when your Activity is being re-created from a previous instance. This happens e.g. when the device changes orientation or when the user navigates away, and then navigates back to your Activity. When the field is set, this allows you to restore the state of the Activity as the user left it.

The `savedInstanceState` field is `null` when your Activity has no previous state to restore from.

When your Activity is about to be destroyed, you can add variables to the `savedInstanceState` by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` in your Activity, and adding them to the `Bundle`. The next time your Activity's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState`) will be called, the fields you set in the `onSaveInstanceState()` will be available to you in the `Bundle`.

Finally, the "application not responsive' dialog is shown when you do too much work on your application's main (UI) Thread. However as pelotasplus mentioned this may also occur when you connect the debugger. If this dialog is shown when you have the debugger attached I wouldn't worry about it. However, if this dialog is shown during normal use of your app, this indicates you perform too much processing on the main Thread and you should move the heavy lifting to background threads, e.g. by using Loader, AsyncTask, IntentService, Thread or any of the other options available for this.

Comment: Perfect!!!! I got everything that I wanted to know and yes I have my debugger attached. There is not so much process in my main thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here, first of all

> saveInstanceState = null

you see in your debugger is nothing unusual. Sometimes it's null, sometimes it's not. This is how Android framework works ;-)

For more information about that go read official docs about Activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

Second thing is that ANR (application not responding) window which happens a lot when debugging your apps.  Just press WAIT and you are good to go.

Comment: As you said Sometime its null sometime its not. But in my case it's happening alternatively. Why it is so?

Comment: just updated my answer, bottom line is that there is activity lifecycle and it's the reason why saveInstanceState is sometimes null and sometimes not

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it.